# The Laplace transform of an integrable function is differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, laplace-transform

let $f\in L^1(0,\infty)$. For x>0, define $g(x)=\int_{0}^{\infty} f(t) e^{-tx} dt$. 
Prove that $f$ is differentiable for $ x>0$ and with derivative
$g'(x) = \int_{0}^{\infty} -tf(t) e^{-tx} dt$.

To show g is differentiable, I tried to use sequence definition of derivatives and wanted to use dominated convergence theorem later I got stuck. Do you have any idea?. Any hints are admirable to this problem.

Comment: It would be good to see how you got stuck. Use definition of the derivative and see what you get.

Comment: Thank you for your concern.let x_n goes to x as n goes to infinty. then g'(x) = lim n goes to infinity {(g(x_n) -g(x))/(x_n-x) then by using the definition of g, we will get limit n goest to infinity in terms of  integral. to bring limit inside the integral I wanted to apply dominated but i could not able to find dominating function.

Comment: You can use the Mean Value Theorem to find that dominating function. if $h>0$ then $(e^{(x+h)t}-e^{xt})/h=\dots\le\dots$

Comment: See [Show that Laplace transform is differentiable](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/84382)