# Prove that $\int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-tx}\frac{\sin x}{x} dx$ is differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives, continuity, lebesgue-integral

I'm trying to prove that
$$F(t) = \int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-tx}\frac{\sin x}{x} dx$$ is differentiable in $]0,+\infty [$. First, $F(t)$ is well defined since $F(t) \leq \int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-tx} dx$ whose integration is finite.

Second, I've tried first to prove that $F(t)$ is continuous using dominated convergence theorem, by that I have to find a domination as an integrable function $g$ so that
$$
\lvert e^{-tx}\frac{\sin x}{x} \rvert \leq g(x)
$$
I've thought of $g(x) = \lvert \frac{\sin x}{x} \rvert$ but it's not a good candidate since it is not Lebesgue integrable. So I've used directly the definition of continuation, it seems good since:
$$
\lvert F(t) - F(t') \rvert \leq \int_{0}^{+\infty} \lvert e^{-tx} - e^{-t'x} \rvert dx \overset{t \to t'}{\to} 0
$$

Third, unfortunately, this direction doesn't help to prove that $F(t)$ is derivable. So, I've came back to the differentiability under domination, it doesn't seem working neither. I've tried to look for a domination of
$$
\lvert (e^{-tx}\frac{\sin x}{x})' \rvert = \lvert t e^{-tx}\frac{\sin x}{x}\rvert
$$
but cannot found any.

Many thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: Not sure if helpful but I assume you know this is a laplace transform.

Comment: What about applying the limit form of the derivative to $F$ directly, then proving you can take the resulting limit inside the integral?

Comment: @eyeballfrog it's not possible to applying the limit form without proving it's derivable first.

Comment: @Sorfosh yes, I'know this is a Laplace transform, but it applies on a non Lebesgue integrable function sin(x)/x, so the dominated convergence theorem does not apply.

Comment: Is this helpful? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84382/show-that-laplace-transform-is-differentiable

Comment: @TaThanhDinh That doesn't sound right. If $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}[F(t + h) - F(t)]/h$ exists at a point, then the function is necessarily differentiable at that point. So all you have to do is show existence of that limit.

Comment: @eyeballfrog I think I've caught your point. The continuity and derivation are local properties, so it's not necessary to look for a domination which works globally with t on R, a domination with local t should be enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $F:(0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by $F(t)=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-tx}\frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx$.
Let $t_{0}\in(0,\infty)$ be arbitrary. We go to show that the derivative
$F'(t_{0})=\int_{0}^{\infty}-e^{-t_{0}x}\sin x\,dx$ . Let $(t_{n})$
be an arbitrary sequence in $(0,\infty)$ such that $t_{n}\neq t_{0}$
and $t_{n}\rightarrow t_{0}$. By Heine's Theorem, to show that $\lim_{t\rightarrow t_{0}}\frac{F(t)-F(t_{0})}{t-t}=\int_{0}^{\infty}-e^{-t_{0}x}\sin x\,dx$,
it suffices that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{F(t_{n})-F(t_{0})}{t_{n}-t_{0}}=\int_{0}^{\infty}-e^{-t_{0}x}\sin x\,dx$.

Since $t_{n}\rightarrow t_{0}>0$ and $t_{n}>0$ for all $n$, there
exists $t'$ such that $0<t'<t_{n}$ for all $n=0,1,2,\ldots$. (For, choose $\delta>0$
such that $t_{0}-\delta>0$. Then there exists $N$ such that $t_{n}\in(t_{0}-\delta,t_{0}+\delta)\setminus\{t_{0}\}$
whenever $n\geq N$. Take $t'=\frac{1}{2}\min\left(t_{1},t_{2},\ldots,t_{N-1},t_{0}-\delta\right)>0$).
For each $n$, define $\theta_{n}:[0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
by $\theta_{n}(x)=\frac{e^{-t_{n}x}-e^{-t_{0}x}}{t_{n}-t_{0}}\cdot\frac{\sin x}{x}$.
Define $\theta:[0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by $\theta(x)=e^{-t'x}$.
For each $x\in[0,\infty)$, by Mean-Value Theorem, there exists $\xi_{x,n}$
strictly between $t_{0}$ and $t_{n}$ such that
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & e^{-t_{n}x}-e^{-t_{0}x}\\
 & = & -(t_{n}x-t_{0}x)e^{-\xi_{x,n}x}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Hence, $\left|\theta_{n}(x)\right|\leq|e^{-\xi_{x,n}x}\sin x|\leq\theta(x)$
because $0<t'\leq\xi_{x,n}$ $\Rightarrow e^{-t'x}\geq e^{-\xi_{x,n}x}$.
Moreover, by direct calculation, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\theta_{n}(x)=-e^{t_{0}x}\sin x$.
Note that $\theta$ is integrable, so by Lebesgue Dominated Convergence
Theorem, we have that
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{F(t_{n})-F(t_{0})}{t_{n}-t_{0}}\\
 & = & \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\theta_{n}(x)dx\\
 & = & \int_{0}^{\infty}\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\theta_{n}(x)dx\\
 & = & \int_{0}^{\infty}-e^{-t_{0}x}\sin x\,dx.
\end{eqnarray*}
We conclude that $F'(t_{0})=\int_{0}^{\infty}-e^{-t_{0}x}\sin x\,dx$.

Answer (score 2):

You can also follow an elementary approach here based on a well-known theorem for interchanging the derivative and limit of a sequence of differentiable functions. Theorem 7.17 in *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Rudin is

> Suppose $(F_n)$ is a sequence of functions, differentiable on $[a,b]$
> and such that $(F_n(t_0))$ converges for some point $t_0 \in [a,b]$.
> If $(F_n')$ converges uniformly on $[a,b]$, then $(F_n)$ converges
> uniformly on $[a,b]$ to a function $F$, and for all $t \in [a,b]$ we
> have $F'(t) = \lim_{n \to \infty}F_n'(t)$.

In this case, we have

$$F_n(t) := \int_{0}^{n} e^{-tx}\frac{\sin x}{x} dx, \quad F'_n(t) = -\int_{0}^{n} e^{-tx}\sin x dx$$

Consider any point $t_0 \in [a,b] \subset (0,\infty)$. The improper integral is convergent (by the Dirichlet test) and

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}F_n(t_0) = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-t_0x}\frac{\sin x}{x} dx$$

Since
$| e^{-tx} \sin x| \leqslant e^{-ax}$ for all $t \in [a,b]$ and $\int_0^\infty e^{-ax} \, dx = \frac{1}{a} < \infty$, it follows by the Weierstrass M-test that $(F_n')$ is uniformly convergent on the interval and applying the theorem we get for all $t \in [a,b]$

$$F'(t) = \lim_{n \to \infty} F_n'(t) = -\int_0^\infty e^{-tx} \sin x \, dx$$

This holds for every $t \in (0,\infty)$ since the choice of $t_0$ and the interval $[a,b]$ was arbitrary.

Answer (score 1):

There is a low-tech solution that is instructive because it uses a method that can cope with amplitudes of slow decay. Exploit the fact that  the humps in the sinc function **decay steadily** and reverse sign with every multiple of $\pi$.

Let $I_n(t)= \int_0^{n \pi} e^{- t x} \frac{ \sin x}{x} dx$ and let $I_{\infty}(t)$ denote the function you wish to show is differentiable.
Regard the integral $I_n$ as the sum of $n$ separate integrals, taken over consecutive intervals of length $\pi$ (the separate humps).

You can use the Leibniz alternating series test to  show  that when $n$ is even,

(i) $ I_{n} (t)\leq I_{\infty}(t)  \leq I_{n+1}(t)$   and

(ii)  the spread between these two endpoints tends to zero as $n\to \infty$.

Consider next $ I'_n(t)=\int_0^{n \pi} -e^{- t x} \sin x dx$ whose integrand also has alternating humps with steadily decreasing mass (because of the exponential decay factor).

By similar reasoning the spread between the derivatives $I'_{n+1}(t)  -I'_n(t)$ tends to zero as $n\to \infty$.
Then use a standard result in  analysis  to show that these Cauchy estimates   are sufficient to justify interchanging limit and derivative.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The key tool here is the following result which is a consequence of
the dominated convergence theorem of Lebesgue. Let $\varphi:X\times(a,b)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
($b$ could be $+\infty$) be such that

1. the function $x\mapsto\varphi(x,t)$ is a Borel function for every
   $t$,
2. the function $t\mapsto\varphi(x,t)$ is a differentiable in $(a,b)$
   for every $x\in X$,
3. $\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial t}(x,t)$ is dominated on $X\times(a,b)$
   by an integrable function $\psi(x)$,

then $F(t):=\int_{X}\varphi(x,t)\,dx$ with $t\in(a,b)$, is differentiable
for every $t\in(a,b)$ and we have
$$
\frac{dF}{dt}(t)=\int_{X}\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial t}(x,t)\,dx.
$$
In the considered case we have

$$
\varphi:\underbrace{\left[0,+\infty\right)}_{X}\times\underbrace{\left(0,\infty\right)}_{(a,b)}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R},\qquad\varphi(x,t)=\frac{\sin x}{x}e^{-tx}.
$$
To show that $F$ is differentiable over $\mathbb{R}_{*}^{+}$ we
need to reason as follows. Let $t_{0}\in\mathbb{R}_{*}^{+}$, then
\begin{equation}\label{eq:1}
\left|\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac{\sin x}{x}e^{-tx}\right|=\left|\sin xe^{-tx}\right|\leqslant e^{-t_{0}x}\qquad\forall(x,t)\in\left[0,+\infty\right)\times\left[t_{0},+\infty\right).\qquad(1)
\end{equation}
This means that $F$ is differentiable on every interval $\left[t_{0},+\infty\right)$
for every $t_{0}\in\left(0,+\infty\right)$, i.e. it is differentiable
over $\left(0,+\infty\right)$.

N.B. we can not consider directly in (1) $\left(0,+\infty\right)$
because in this case we can not get a dominating function which is
integrable over $\left[0,+\infty\right)$ (indeed, for every $x\in\left[0,+\infty\right),$
$\sup_{t\in\left(0,+\infty\right)}\left|\sin xe^{-tx}\right|=\left|\sin x\right|$).

\medskip

Another possible way to establish the asked differentiability property is related to the fact that the considered integral can be interpret as the Laplace transform of the function $\frac{\sin x}{x}$, i.e., setting $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}$,
$$
F(t)=\mathcal{L}[f(\cdot)](t):=\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x}e^{-tx}\,dx.
$$ There is a general result guaranteeing that $F$ is differentiable for every $t\in\mathbb{R}^+_*$. It suffices for example that there exists a $n\in\mathbb{N}_*$ such that $\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x^n}=0$. This requirement guarantees that we can differentiate under the sign of integral. Indeed it is know that (a consequence of the dominated Lebesgue theorem) if $\varphi:X\times(a,b)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

@Danny has shown a solution which evaluates the derivative of $F(t)$ via its definition. Another approach is to uses directly the differentiability under domination, it is suggested by Sorfosh via a very similar [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/228212).

The idea is that the differentiability is a local property, to prove that $F(t)$ is differentiable at a point $t_0$ it's enough to consider a neighbourhood $]t_0 - \epsilon, t_0+\epsilon[ \subset ]0,+\infty[$. In that interval:

$$
\lvert (e^{-tx} \frac{\sin x}{x})' \rvert = e^{-tx} \lvert \sin x \rvert \leq e^{-(t_0 - \epsilon)x}
$$

Moreover

$$
\int_0^{+\infty} e^{-(t_0 - \epsilon)x} dx = \frac{1}{t_0-\epsilon} < +\infty
$$
then we can apply the theorem of convergence under domination.